# Can you a return a whole object as a string using string template literals?

Tags: javascript, string, object

I have this question:

> This function should take an argument as an object, and return a string with the user's details in the form:
>
> ```
> 'name: Mitch, age: 27, language: Javascript'
> ```
>
> Note - this is a good use case of string template literals.

```
function createUserString(userObj) {

}
```

Can anyone help explain how to convert an objects properties into a full string?

Comment: This involves putting two concepts together: (1) accessing properties on an object and (2) concatenating strings (probably using a template literal as the question suggests). Which one are you stuck on? As written, all that can be done for this question is just give you the answer, which I don't think is very educational. Just showing the function stub doesn't seem like a true attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: No, you're absolutely correct and please don't misconstrue my question as simply a lazy attempt to find the answer. It would be one thing finding the answer, but when the issue creeps up again i'd be no better off. So far i've tried to use string literals however i just put ${userObj}, because I don't 'technically' know the keys in the object.

Comment: I've tried Object.keys() and Object.values() and somehow trying to concatenate the two but that was a pipe dream.

Comment: return `name: ${userObj.name}, age: ${userObj.age}, language: ${userObj.language}`;
}

Comment: So that seems like it should work. I guess I'm not really clear what the problem is.

Comment: Yes that does work, I was seeing if anyone could help me get that ^^ point across, I didn't know to write it but I figured it, I should have been clearer my apologies

Answer (score 1):

I think using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) together can solve your issue. Read from their documentations:

> The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.
>
> The Object.entries() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable string-keyed property [key, value] pairs, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop.

See a possible good solution:

```js
const user = {
  name: 'Mitch',
  age: 27,
  language: 'JavaScript',
  nickName: 'Cool Mitch' // just added one more property for representation
};

const createUserString = user => {
  const entries = Object.entries(user);
  return entries.reduce((a, [k,v]) => a ? `${a}, ${k}: ${v}` : `${k}: ${v}`, '');
}

console.log(createUserString(user));
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: What if `user` has more properties than `name` `age` and `language`?

Comment: @ggorlen It will still work, just added one more property to represent.

Comment: `nickName: Cool Mitch` is not part of the expected output though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const person = {
  name: 'Mitch',
  age: 27,
  language: 'Javascript'
};

const res = Object.entries(person)
                  .map(([k, v]) => `${k}: ${v}`)
                  .join(', ');

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with object distructuring

```js
function createUserString({name, age, language}) {
   return `Name: ${name}, Age:${age}, Language:${language}`;
}

let user = {
  name: 'Mitch', 
  age: 27, 
  language: 'Javascript'
}

console.log(createUserString(user))
```

Comment: @Addis the format of the expected output existed in the original version of the question as well.

Comment: So you are saying 'name' is missing before the name and for other properties as well?

Comment: For this to work would I not have to change the arguments of the function to name, age and language?

Comment: The function accepts an object, what I did inside the function argument is assign the object properties to variables. This is called destructuring, it simplifies the process. You use it just like I did in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could try iterating over object's enumerable properties using lodash's `forOwn` and concatenating it into a string using template strings:

```
function createUserString(userObj){
    let result = "";
    _.forOwn(userObj, (value, key) => {
        result += `${value}: ${key},`;
    }
    return result;

}
```